# Deleted content type shows in the "Add content" menu

Tags: nodes

I had some content types I wanted to delete so I went to Structure >> Content types. I deleted the content types that I didn't want to have anymore, and I cleared all the cache through drush and performance.

I also went to my database and look through to double check if they were deleted, and I found they were deleted correctly.

I have also restarted my MAMP local server.

The problem is that the deleted content types appears on "Add content" but they are not clickable. I don't want them to appear there. why does this happen?

Comment: Probably someone manually added / edited menu entries for them. Can't you just manually delete them?

Comment: No, I'm the only one devolping the site. It's under progress. There is no entries for them.

Comment: Magic happens. Flushing menu registry should help. But clearing all caches should have it done for you already.

Comment: Content types added by modules are implemented in hook_menu often times. So, I would bet that the contrib module that created the content type is to blame.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem which I just managed to fix - thanks to  Mołot's comment which made me think of menus.  It looks like creating a content type adds an entry to the Navigation menu but deleting it doesn't delete the entry.  I just disabled that menu item and now it's gone from the Add Content page.